# Цвет текста заголовков TabHost

Tags: android

Как поменять цвет текста заголовков вкладок в TabHost на белый?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TextView tv = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
```

Comment: А разом для всех нельзя выставить нужный цвет не обращаясь по индексу каждый раз?

Comment: Не знаю, с `TabLayout` через `ViewPager` вроде проще все.

Comment: А есть ссылка на нормальный пример по TabLayout?

Comment: http://www.fandroid.info/kak-sozdat-vkladki-tablayout-v-stile-material-design/